# What is the return response from SQSClient.send()?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I can't seem to find a proper API reference to SQSClient's send function within the official AWS docs. Is it just missing? What is returned from the `SQSClient.send(command)` line they have in the [example code for sending a message](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_sqs_code_examples.html):

```
import { SendMessageCommand, SQSClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";

const client = new SQSClient({});
const SQS_QUEUE_URL = "queue_url";

export const main = async (sqsQueueUrl = SQS_QUEUE_URL) => {
  const command = new SendMessageCommand({
    QueueUrl: sqsQueueUrl,
    DelaySeconds: 10,
    MessageAttributes: {
      Title: {
        DataType: "String",
        StringValue: "The Whistler",
      },
      Author: {
        DataType: "String",
        StringValue: "John Grisham",
      },
      WeeksOn: {
        DataType: "Number",
        StringValue: "6",
      },
    },
    MessageBody:
      "Information about current NY Times fiction bestseller for week of 12/11/2016.",
  });

  const response = await client.send(command);
  console.log(response); // <-------------------------- What will this output?
  return response;
};
```

Comment: The v3 SDK is well typed, your IDE can tell you exactly what `response` is (it's a [`SendMessageCommandOutput`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/91ee452ab2178c6aed3b5b5d9dbc9c5b294c8e29/clients/client-sqs/src/commands/SendMessageCommand.ts#L177), in the first instance, which is a `SendMessageResult` and `__MetadataBearer`).

Comment: I'd looked into that but didn't get anywhere! I think it was because I'd tried delving into the `.send` function itself, but going through the actual Type being suggested I managed to find the answer, even if it's not so helpful XD